# Can someone explain me the row and bucket concept for Hystrix metrics?

Tags: metrics, hystrix

I read it about metrics concept of Hystrix but I didn't understand why use rows and buckets within rolling window.

**Why in buckets and not total value?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this is merely a performance optimization.

In Hystrix writes to metrics happen at the volume of command executions, which is in the 1000s of executions/second on a single instance.

If you would have to re-calculate the aggregate view of metrics every time a single metric was received, this would be prohibitively expensive.

Instead, they found that putting metrics into time-buckets allowed to only recalculate aggregate metrics on bucket boundaries without sacrificing much accuracy.

See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/issues/1394)